# MySQL Query and select data from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
taxonomy_index
-nid
-tid
```

and

```
url_alias
-source 
-alias
```

I need to find `url_alias.alias` record which have source `'taxonomy/term/' + taxonomy_index.tid` and I have only `taxonomy_index.nid`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT url_alias.alias 
  FROM url_alias, taxonomy_index 
 WHERE url_alias.source = CONCATENATE('taxonomy/term/', taxonomy_index.tid) 
   AND taxonomy_index.nid = {given_nid}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use a subquery or a join. With a subquery:

```
SELECT alias
FROM url_alias 
WHERE source = 
 (SELECT CONCAT('taxonomy/term/',tid)
  FROM taxonomy_index
  WHERE nid = ?
 )
```

Comment: Just be aware that subqueries alone are very slow, and especially when you are using CONCAT. Just a heads up

Answer (score 1):

This query will do that for you although there may be more efficient way to do this ;)

```
SELECT
    T.nid
   ,U.*
FROM
   url_alias AS U
   INNER JOIN (
     SELECT
        nid
       ,CONCAT('taxonomy/term/', tid) AS `alias`
     FROM
       taxonomy_index ) AS T
     ON
     U.alias = T.alias
```